# Why use bitwise operators for checking mouse clicks?

Tags: .net, mouse, bit-manipulation

I usually write the following to handle a right mouse click.

if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
   {
   }

But, I have seen people do it this way.  Can somebody tell me why they do it this way? What's the advantage?

if ((e.Button & MouseButtons.Right) == MouseButtons.Right)
   {
   }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any reason to use `(e.Button & MouseButtons.Right) == MouseButtons.Right` expression in `MouseDown` event handler, but it makes more sense in `MouseMove` event handler. When user moves cursor over control with several buttons pressed, this code detects if right mouse button pressed (other buttons can also be pressed), while `e.Button == MouseButtons.Right` means that only the right button is pressed.